# Taking out common config of jenkins jobs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I have about 200 jenkins, each of them has a long config page but actually most config are the same. Everytime when I need to update something in the common config, I write a groovy script to loop though those jobs and update them one by one. It's a pain because it takes about 5 minutes to update those jobs by the groovy script. I am wondering is there a jenkins plugin(or something else) that I can use to put the common config in one place? jenkins slicing plugin doesn't work well, I think it conflicts with another plugin.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a job for the [job-dsl plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Job+DSL+Plugin)

From the wiki page

> The Jenkins job-dsl-plugin attempts to solve this problem by allowing
>   jobs to be defined with the absolute minimum necessary in a
>   programmatic form, with the help of templates that are synced with the
>   generated jobs. The goal is for your project to be able to define all
>   the jobs they want to be related to their project, declaring their
>   intent for the jobs, leaving the common stuff up to a template that
>   were defined earlier or hidden behind the DSL.